# Do links to Wikipedia hurt the site?

Tags: discussion

A comment to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions/8729#8729) says:

> The reason such a problem even exist is because Google has assigned a high "value" to SE pages. If more than x% of SE is filled with lmgtfy, Google would soon self-adjust (by lowering SE's search ranking) and the problem would be solved. – Pacerier

This got me wondering about linking to other sites in large quantities, and whether this might have an impact on where Music.SE appears in search results. In particular, I link to Wikipedia with some regularity so that people who want to read more have a resource. I got the idea from other answers that did this too. But I had never considered that this practice might cause Music.SE pages to appear lower in Google search results. Is there any real risk of this, or is not an issue because it would require vastly more links to Wikipedia than currently exist?

Comment: A link to wikipedia is not the same as lmgtfy. In fact, I'm struggling to understand the connection you are making here between the linked SE meta question and whether links to Wikipedia pages are used in answers. What is the connection?

Comment: This is really just what initiated my train of thought. The question I want to focus on is whether lots of links pointing from this site to Wikipedia will tend to boost Wikipedia above Music.SE in Google search results (or other search engine search results). I'll clarify

Comment: Wikipedia typically isn't the best reference for music theory. Some articles are good while others need a ton of work and have misleading or plain wrong info. That being said, there are much worse sources out there for music(I can point out a few if requested). So as long as we do our due diligence and point out when sources are wrong we should be good.

Comment: @Dom, agreed! Check out [this answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/66336/40842), for example, which cites 4 Wikipedia articles. I feel like that sort of thing isn't too uncommon on Music.SE (and this isn't a criticism--I've done it too). I have some vague recollection that Google's search optimization assigns higher rank to pages/sites that are linked to by other highly-ranked sources. So if Music.SE (a reputable, highly-ranked site) links heavily to Wikipedia, then might Google begin ranking Wikipedia pages above Music.SE in search results?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I can totally relate. I have that feeling too about Wikipedia. Sometimes I feel like it gives enough for the person to ask intelligent questions--that is, it provides enough for them to initiate further research on their own.